# How to get DigitalProductId from Registry via TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, registry

Currently have this to get a value from the registry in TSQL. However, I need to get the DigitalProductId and it does not return the value required. I think its stored as a binary in the registry.

Any ideas?

```
DECLARE @retvalue int, @data varchar(500)
EXECUTE @retvalue = master.dbo.xp_instance_regread 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion',
'DigitalProductId', @param = @data OUTPUT
PRINT 'ProductId: '+ @data
```

**Edit:** I have updated the question and the code.

Comment: It works for me. What are you getting? Empty? Error?

Comment: Also works for me.  Does this fail on one instance, all instances, from one client, all clients?  Being a little more specific than "it appears to not work" would be helpful.

Comment: I have updated the question slightly and the code now contains the "DigitalProductId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DigitalProductId` is a `REG_BINARY` key.

`xp_instance_regread` casts everything it reads into a null-terminated string, so this won't ever return anything meaningful if the string contains `NULLs`.

`xp_instance_regread` is an undocumented procedure that is not intended to be used in production environment. If you need to read the registry keys from `SQL Server`'s side, you better write your own `XP` to do it.

Comment: So, it is possible to CAST back to a displayable value? The DigitalProductId is like this PWK9P-6GFTM-792RH-JDM92-TXV9E when properly extracted from the registry.

Comment: It needs to work in all versions of SQL (2000, 2005 , 2008) including express editions. This proc is built in and I didnt think it was possible to do any other way unless a CLR proc is developed which would require 2005 minimum and clr enabled as a pre-req.

Comment: `@Coolcoder`: The `XP` just returns a pointer to the data, which `SQL Server` casts into a `VARCHAR` (since that's what the `XP` expects). The data contains double zeros which are treated as the string separators and the string is truncated on them. So when the registry value reaches the `SQL Server`, everything after the first zero will be irrecoverably lost.

Comment: @Quassnoi So it isnt possible without resulting to a CLR proc?

Comment: `@Coolcoder`: this is not a `CLR`, this is an extended stored procedure. This works from `2000` onwards (and probably, even earlier)

Comment: @Quassnoi Sorry, I know the current proc is not a CLR proc. What I mean is, it sounds like the current XP cannot output what I require so  the question is, is it possible to get what I need without resulting to using a CLR?

Answer (score 0):

you can get around the string truncation as follows:

```
declare @DigitalProductID varbinary(16);
declare @xp_instance_regread table ([key] nvarchar(128), [value] varbinary(16));
insert into @xp_instance_regread
exec master..xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_Machine',N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',N'DigitalProductID'
select @DigitalProductID = [value] from @xp_instance_regread
select 'DigitalProductID',@DigitalProductID
```

Comment: Only works if the value is below a length of 254 byte.